# R - Plotting two variables as lines on ggplot 2

Tags: r, linegraph

I am trying to plot this data frame on one line graph (with points) using ggplot2, i have managed it on excel easy enough but i would like to generate it in R.

```
Wakatobi <- read.table("Wakatobi SST.txt", header=T)
Wakatobi
```

[image: Link To Data Frame in R Studio]

[image: Link to excel graph]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow . please read the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3):

You need to first melt your data using reshape.

```
df <- data.frame(Month = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr"),
                 Var1 = rnorm(4),
                 Var2 = rnorm(4) + 1)

df2 <- melt(df, id.vars="Month", measure.vars=c("Var1", "Var2"))

ggplot(df2, aes(x=Month, y=value, group=variable, color=variable)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
```

Comment: Thanks but i still don't really understand how i translate this to my data frame.

Comment: Actually figured it out now great thanks. God my R skills are so rusty at the moment. Thanks again!